# Is it true that 'socialization' solves all problems?

Tags: ethics

I have discovered the following formula : If any problem then socialize with right people.
If hungry then I look for cook. If sad then I look for entertainers. If any dispute then I seek a authority. I tend to socialize for almost every problem.
My question is : Should we declare that 'if problem then socialize with right people' formula to be true forever ?

Comment: "If any dispute then I seek a powerful , just king." I guess this use of formula is too naïve. An authority can take position against yours and your problem gets even worse.

Comment: Your post is not really an answerable question but a description of your thoughts on a subject inviting other users to share theirs. This is suitable for a forum but here is considered off-topic. We take more pointed questions that are more or less objectively answerable based on existing literature.

Comment: @Conifold, I'm wondering if any question asking "Is it true that X?" is unanswerable within philosophy. Even more, if philosophy ever answers such questions. If not, then any such question is off-topic, but is the answer "no"?

Comment: The reason such questions are unanswerable is that philosophy, unlike science, does not look for yes/no answers. On any non-trivial question there are philosophical positions that answer it in opposing ways. The answer to your question taken literally is a trivial "no" because of "all", but taking it as a rhetorical exaggeration you'll probably find people coming from different perspectives arguing for more or for less socialization. Nietzsche, for instance, would condemn social overreliance as [slave morality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93slave_morality).

Answer (score 1):

You need a very broad definition of 'socialize', but in some sense, I would have to say that you are right.

Take science for an example. Clearly the scientists who made great original discoveries didn't do so by going to more intelligent scientists. Those people had their own theories, and those theories lost out.  So there is not always someone to ask.

Science finds answers, but no individual gives them.  It is a grand social process.  Large parts of it take part alone, but only in negotiation with yourself in the face of your data.  The middle parts really are just socialization with your peers.  And the more important parts take place in arguments played out over centuries by a succession of different players.  But all along, the entire thing is a conversation of one sort of another, an ongoing process of socialization.

Religion is another big social club, even if some of its contributors are mystical anchorites who just write down their experiences and never hear an answer to what they said.

This is another form of Wittgenstein's notion of the language-game.  All the important questions in life are really answered in a sort of alternately competitive and consensus-building negotiation process.  Truth is social, but on an iterlocking set of scales that span down to your own competing opinions in your head, and up to the gifts that civilizations make to posterity when they collapse.

Answer (score 0):

What about the problem of wanting to be alone right now?  It seems that that can't be solved by socializing.